# is there a way to choose which side to position against in css..if no will there be?

Tags: css

There are two things with positioning in css.

First, when using **absolute** if you write `right:33px;` the space will be put between right side of the div and the parent's right side. Isn't there a way to choose the side, so i can tell browser to put  x amount of space between div's **left** side and **parent's right side**. I know it can be overcome using `calc()` in future css or javascript now. But is there anything css only now?

2nd, with **relative** when you put `right:33px;` it moves as if the anchor is at x:0, y:0 of the element. And you are merely translating it. It's all useful in many conditions. But is there a way to position it like absolute..so instead of using its own position as reference point it could use its parent's. Maybe there could be another mode which is between relative and absolute. It position itself relative to parent (and not itself) and still not go out of flow & keep its space.

### Summary:

**absolute:** positioned relative to parent, but is taken out flow.

**relative:** positioned relative to itself, but there is no way to define distance relationship between it and parent's side. Place is preserved in flow.

Comment: I can't quite understand what you're asking - could you give an example of what you're trying to achieve?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/3ULLk/

Comment: You'd like to align the *right* side of a child element with the *left* side of the parent element?

Comment: as you can see in scenario in jsfiddle...so i am trying to ask if there is css way that is not broken when it comes to defining which side browser should position when using top, `right`, `left`, & `bottom`. Basically if i set `right: 13px;` it should stick 13px from it's right side not left as it'd normally would.

Comment: you can say that Note child's width can be varied.

Answer (score 1):

CSS 2.1 Section [9.4.1](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visuren.html#block-formatting) Block formatting contexts

> In a block formatting context, each box's left outer edge touches the
>   left edge of the containing block (for right-to-left formatting, right
>   edges touch). This is true even in the presence of floats (although a
>   box's line boxes may shrink due to the floats), unless the box
>   establishes a new block formatting context (in which case the box
>   itself may become narrower due to the floats).

So by setting the context's direction (right-to-left OR left-to-right) you can have control on that.

Related CSS property: [`direction`](http://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/direction)

Comment: this is useful but it messes up the parent element.

Answer (score 0):

This is a half-guess as I'm still not entirely sure what you want, but is it this?

http://jsfiddle.net/3ULLk/1/

By setting `right: 100%;` you can get the right side of the element to stick to the left side of its parent. You can then joggle it left or right by using margins if you want to, and it'll work regardless of the element size.

Comment: yes that's working very well

Comment: even though not exactly the control i wanted but still the one that works.

Comment: though it doesn't work always http://jsfiddle.net/h3za6/2/

Comment: @MuhammadUmer: Now you're doing something completely different and again I have no idea what it is you're trying to do...

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/3ULLk/2/

Comment: @MuhammadUmer: That link doesn't really tell me anything. You'll have to use your words to explain what you want.

Comment: Ok, well there are some boxes that are inside one main box. They have different widths and they are pushed to left. How much they have been pushed appears to be based on their width..or in other way of putting their distance from box and their right side is the same. And this can be done if they are absolutely positioned and placed inside one more div to prevent the from collapsing into one line. But http://jsfiddle.net/JBX5k/ as you can see there..if absolute positioning is avoided then `100%` right doesn't work/(has intended effect).

Comment: i also updated the question...